# pySpark performance issue - repeatedly query rawdata

Tags: pyspark, query-optimization

I'm using pySpark to query a large data set in AWS S3 bucket with below code. The rawdata query is very slow. Therefore I'm trying to improve the performance with cache and temp views. But looks like it doesn't work.

```
baseName = "/local/rawdata"
df_data = spark.read.parquet(baseName)

df_data = df_data.filter(df_data["supplyUuid"]=="xxxxxxxxx...")
df_data = df_data.select(["subscriptionState", "dateTime"])
df_data.cache().createOrReplaceTempView("subscriptionHistory")
display(df_data)
```

Here I get a two columns table with 93 recorders.

Then I run below code to get the start and end date time of different subscription states.

```
df_data.groupBy("subscriptionState").agg(f.min("dateTime"), f.max("dateTime"))
```

Suppose, I've already cache the subset data with 93 recorders in a temp table. The group is run based on the subset. But actually I found the 2nd part of the code takes hours and seems like it query the whole rawdata again.

What happens here? How to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to explain Spark has a lazy execution model, which means any transformations will not be executed unless there is an action coming at the end.

So calling `cache` will only cache the results while executing the first action at the end, so you will benefit from caching unless you are going to reuse the same dataframe in another action.

So calling `cache` then `createOrReplaceTempView` then `groupby` won't be executed immediately, and the execution time is for the whole operation from reading the files until the group by and aggregations.

Since I'm not aware of your complete logic and enviroment, I'd suggest to start with the `repartition` so you can split the load on more workers.

You can find also more tuning tips from the official [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#coalesce-hints-for-sql-queries).

Comment: It takes 2 hours to get result from display(df_data). It should run the query to pull the data.  I've already seen 93 recorders in the dataset. Then I ran the groupBy, it still took another hour to get result.

Comment: What does the `display(df_data)` do? Collect? Also the `df.select` i assume it is just a typo it should be `df_data.select`? Also after display the 93 records do you see the df cached from Spark Ui Storage tab?

Comment: yes, you are right. df.select should be df_data.select.  When I run display(df_data), it does collect the rawdata and show me the complete dataset I required.  How to check Spark Ui Storage tab? I use databrick and don't know how to check the cache and temp tables.

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/debugging-spark-ui.html.   To check if the df is cached add `print df_data.is_cached` after `display`